# Temporal combination of Raster files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python

I have a set of time series daily raster files, I want to have a temporal combination on daily bases. As an example I want to combine day1 with day2 and day2 with day3 and so on.
The file name are exactly same and just date is varying in the file in the sequence of (2010001,2010002,2010003....). 
I want to edit [if item1.endswith(item2[32:51]):] to match file with its proceedings file.

```
import  arcpy
import os
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\BRB Snow Cover\Sample\Terra'
Terra_Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MOD*")
matches = 0
for item1 in Terra_Rasters:
    for item2 in Terra_Rasters:
        print item1
        print item2
        if item1.endswith(item2[32:37]):
        print "Match"
        output = "D:\\BRB Snow Cover\\Sample\\output""\\" + str(item1) + '.tif'
            arcpy.gp.Con_sa(item1,item2,output,item1,"\"Value\" =8")
        else:
            print "No"
            matches = matches+1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Are they the same location and you want to add then together? So if a cell had 4 and the other had 5 you what 9? If so look at the plus tool in spatial analysts toolbox.

Comment: All file are in same directory and I want to add two file together in row, for example they one and two will combine together and overwrite on day two, the result of these two should be combined with day 3 and overwrite on day 3. This procedure will continue till end.

Comment: So what code have you written so far?

Comment: I have another script combining different raster like A1.tif and B1.tif. The script matching 1 at both. This time I need to match 1&2, 2&3. I really don't know the code.

Comment: You should edit your question and show the user community what you have done so far.

Comment: I edit the question as your comment, please let me know if you have solution on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below script with help of @Hornbydd script and it works in my case:

```
import  arcpy
import os
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\BRB Snow Cover\Sample\Terra'
Terra_Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MOD*")
matches = 1
for item1 in Terra_Rasters:
    for item2 in Terra_Rasters:
        item1_num = int(item1[31:38])
        item2_num = int(item2[31:38])
        if (item2_num - 1) == item1_num:
            print item1
            print item2
            print "Match"
            output = "D:\\BRB Snow Cover\\Sample\\output1""\\" + str(item2) + '.tif'
            arcpy.gp.Con_sa(item2, item1, output, item2, "\"Value\" =8")
        else:
            print "No"
            matches = matches + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure GIS question it's more about dealing with python in a GIS context. The following code should help you develop your code further:

```py
r1 = r"c:\temp\2010001.tif"
r2 = r"c:\temp\2010002.tif"
r1_num = int(r1[12:15]) # returns 1
r2_num = int(r2[12:15]) # returns 2
if (r2_num - 1) == r1_num:
    print "r2 is 1 day ahead of r1 do something"
```

Comment: I run the script and get the below error. I have a big raster list and want to have a batch process. "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

Comment: Looking at your new code and error message I can only guess that the file names are not consistent in length and the text slice 31:38 is returning a string that cannot be converted to a number, you need to improve your code to check that the slice 31:38 is in fact returning a number.